# If setting/updating state is async, how does 'resetting' the input field work?

Tags: reactjs

If setting/updating state is async, how is it that this works fine?

```
  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
 
    const dataObj = {
      title,
      amount,
      date: new Date(date),
    };
 
    console.log(dataObj);
    setTitle("");       <~ these three lines. How is it that they work?
    setAmount("");
    setDate("");
  };
```

Comment: What makes you think that resetting the inputs like that shouldn't work just because state updates are async?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this!

```
const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
 
    const dataObj = {
      title,
      amount,
      date: new Date(date),
    };
 
    console.log(dataObj);
    setTitle(() => {title: dataObj.title});        
    setAmount(() => {amount: dataObj.amount});
    setDate(() => {date: dataObj.date});
  };
```